# I don’t understand how to solve the error as "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (396) into shape (434)"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
import numpy as np
import time

import tensorflow as tf

def conv_res_part_P(P_t,f,is_training,var_name):

    epsilon=0.0001
    f0=5
    s0=1

    print('conv2 out P', X)
   
    return X

def conv_res_part_E(E_t,f,is_training,var_name):

    epsilon=0.0001
    f0=5
    s0=1
    #############stage 1

    X = tf.layers.conv1d(E_t, filters=8, kernel_size=9, strides=1, padding='valid',
                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), activation=None,
                         name='Conv00' + var_name, data_format='channels_last', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

    X = tf.nn.relu(X)
    X = tf.layers.average_pooling1d(X, pool_size=2, strides=2, data_format='channels_last', name='average_pool')

    X = tf.layers.conv1d(X, filters=12, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='valid',
                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), activation=None,
                         name='Conv0' + var_name, data_format='channels_last', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

    X = tf.nn.relu(X)

    X = tf.layers.average_pooling1d(X, pool_size=2, strides=2, data_format='channels_last', name='average_pool')

    X = tf.layers.conv1d(X, filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='valid',
                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), activation=None,
                         name='Conv1'+var_name, data_format='channels_last',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)



    X = tf.nn.relu(X)
    X = tf.layers.average_pooling1d(X, pool_size=2, strides=2, data_format='channels_last', name='average_pool')
    print('conv1 out E',X)


    X = tf.layers.conv1d(X, filters=20, kernel_size=3, strides=s0, padding='valid',
                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), activation=None,
                         name='Conv2'+var_name, data_format='channels_last',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    X = tf.nn.relu(X)
    X = tf.layers.average_pooling1d(X, pool_size=2, strides=2, data_format='channels_last', name='average_pool')


    print('E outttt',X)



    return X




def conv_res_part_S(S_t,f,is_training,var_name):




    X = tf.layers.conv1d(S_t, filters=4, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='valid',
                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), activation=None,
                         name='Conv1'+var_name, data_format='channels_last',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)



    X = tf.nn.relu(X)

    #print('conv1 out S'+' '+var_name,X)

    X = tf.layers.average_pooling1d(X, pool_size=2, strides=2, data_format='channels_last', name='average_pool')

    X = tf.layers.conv1d(X, filters=8, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='valid',
                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), activation=None,
                         name='Conv2'+var_name, data_format='channels_last',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)


    X = tf.nn.relu(X)

    #print('conv2 out S' + ' ' + var_name, X)

    X = tf.layers.conv1d(X, filters=12, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding='valid',
                         kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), activation=None,
                         name='Conv3'+var_name, data_format='channels_last',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

    X = tf.nn.relu(X)

    #print('conv3 out S' + ' ' + var_name, X)

    return X






def main_proccess(E_t1,E_t2,E_t3,E_t4,E_t5,E_t6,S_t1,S_t2,S_t3,S_t4,S_t5,S_t6,S_t7,S_t8,S_t9,S_t10,P_t,Ybar,S_t_extra,f,is_training,num_units,num_layers,dropout):

    
e_out1 = conv_res_part_E(E_t1, f, is_training=is_training,var_name='v1')
    e_out1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out1)
    e_out2 = conv_res_part_E(E_t2, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1')
    e_out2 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out2)
    e_out3 = conv_res_part_E(E_t3, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1')
    e_out3 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out3)
    e_out4 = conv_res_part_E(E_t4, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1')
    e_out4 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out4)
    e_out5 = conv_res_part_E(E_t5, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1')
    e_out5 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out5)
    e_out6 = conv_res_part_E(E_t6, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1')
    e_out6 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out6)


    #print('E output----', e_out1)
    #e_out = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out)

    e_out=tf.concat([e_out1,e_out2,e_out3,e_out4,e_out5,e_out6],axis=1)
    print('after concatenate',e_out)

    e_out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=e_out, num_outputs=40, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                              weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                              biases_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    e_out=tf.nn.relu(e_out)
    print('e_out_*************',e_out)

    s_out1 = conv_res_part_S(S_t1, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out1)
    s_out2 = conv_res_part_S(S_t2, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out2 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out2)
    s_out3 = conv_res_part_S(S_t3, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out3 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out3)
    s_out4 = conv_res_part_S(S_t4, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out4 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out4)
    s_out5 = conv_res_part_S(S_t5, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out5 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out5)
    s_out6 = conv_res_part_S(S_t6, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out6 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out6)

    #s_out7 = conv_res_part_S(S_t7, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    #s_out7 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out7)
    s_out7 = conv_res_part_S(S_t7, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out7 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out7)
    s_out8 = conv_res_part_S(S_t8, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out8 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out8)
    s_out9 = conv_res_part_S(S_t9, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out9 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out9)
    s_out10 = conv_res_part_S(S_t10, f, is_training=is_training, var_name='v1S')
    s_out10 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(s_out10)

    p_out=conv_res_part_P(P_t,f,is_training,var_name='P')
    p_out=tf.contrib.layers.flatten(p_out)

    print('p outtttttt',p_out)
    # print('E output----', e_out1)
    # e_out = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(e_out)

    s_out = tf.concat([s_out1, s_out2, s_out3, s_out4, s_out5, s_out6,s_out7,s_out8,s_out9,s_out10], axis=1)
    print('soil after concatenate', s_out)

    s_out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=s_out, num_outputs=40, activation_fn=None,
                                               weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                               biases_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())



    s_out = tf.nn.relu(s_out)


    print('soil after FC layer', s_out)

    e_out=tf.concat([e_out,s_out,p_out],axis=1)

    print('soil + Weather after concatante', e_out)

    time_step=5
 e_out=tf.reshape(e_out,shape=[-1,time_step,e_out.get_shape().as_list()[-1]])

    print('e_out_after_reshapeeeee',e_out)
    S_t_extra=tf.reshape(S_t_extra,shape=[-1,time_step,4])
    e_out=tf.concat([e_out,Ybar,S_t_extra],axis=-1)
    #e_out = tf.concat([e_out, Ybar], axis=-1)


    #print('E output_flatten----', e_out)

    #e_out=tf.transpose(e_out,[0,2,1])

    #print(e_out,'transposed')


    #merged=tf.concat([g_out,e_out],axis=1)
    #merged = tf.concat([g_out, E_t], axis=1)



    cells = []

    for _ in range(num_layers):
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units)

        #cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell(num_units)

        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout)

        cells.append(cell)

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)



    output, _= tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, e_out, dtype=tf.float32)

    print('RNN output',output)



    output=tf.reshape(output,shape=[-1,output.get_shape().as_list()[-1]])


    output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=output, num_outputs=1, activation_fn=None,
                                               weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                               biases_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    print(output)

    output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[-1,5])
    print("output of all time steps", output)
    Yhat1 = tf.gather(output, indices=[4], axis=1)

    print('Yhat1111111111', Yhat1)

    Yhat2 = tf.gather(output, indices=[0,1,2,3], axis=1)
    print('Yhat222222', Yhat2)

    return Yhat1,Yhat2



def Cost_function(Y, Yhat):

    E = Y - Yhat
    E2 = tf.pow(E, 2)

    MSE = tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_mean(E2))
    RMSE = tf.pow(MSE, 0.5)
    Loss = tf.losses.huber_loss(Y, Yhat, weights=1.0, delta=5.0)

    return RMSE, MSE, E, Loss





def get_sample(dic,L,avg,batch_size,time_steps,num_features):


    L_tr=L[:-1,:]

   # L_tr=L_tr[20:,:]

    out=np.zeros(shape=[batch_size,time_steps,num_features])

    for i in range(batch_size):

        r1 = np.squeeze(np.random.randint(L_tr.shape[0], size=1))

        years = L_tr[r1, :]

        for j, y in enumerate(years):
            X = dic[str(y)]
            ym=avg[str(y)]
            r2 = np.random.randint(X.shape[0], size=1)
            #n=X[r2, :]
            out[i, j, :] = np.concatenate((X[r2, :],np.array([[ym]])),axis=1)


    return out



def get_sample_te(dic,mean_last,avg,batch_size_te,time_steps,num_features):

    out = np.zeros(shape=[batch_size_te, time_steps, num_features])

    X = dic[str(2018)]

   # r1 = np.random.randint(X.shape[0], size=batch_size_te)
    out[:, 0:4, :] += mean_last.reshape(1,4,3+6*52+1+100+14+4)
    #n=X[r1, :]
    #print(n.shape)
    ym=np.zeros(shape=[batch_size_te,1])+avg['2018']

    out[:,4,:]=np.concatenate((X,ym),axis=1)

    return out







def main_program(X, Index,num_units,num_layers,Max_it, learning_rate, batch_size_tr,le,l):





    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

        #G_t=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,Gn,3],dtype=tf.float32,name='G_t') # channel last


        E_t1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 52,1], dtype=tf.float32, name='E_t1')  #70 * 4 yeras

        E_t2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 52, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='E_t2')  # 70 * 4 yeras

        E_t3 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 52, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='E_t3')  # 70 * 4 yeras
        E_t4 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 52, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='E_t4')  # 70 * 4 yeras
        E_t5 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 52, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='E_t5')  # 70 * 4 yeras
        E_t6 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 52, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='E_t6')  # 70 * 4 yeras



        S_t1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10,1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t1')

        S_t2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10,1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t2')

        S_t3 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t3')

        S_t4 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t4')

        S_t5 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t5')

        S_t6 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t6')

        S_t7 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t7')

        S_t8 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t8')

        S_t9 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t9')

        S_t10 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t10')

        S_t_extra=tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 4,1], dtype=tf.float32, name='S_t_extra')

        P_t = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 14, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name='P_t')  #Plant Data




        Ybar=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,5,1], dtype=tf.float32, name='Ybar')


        Y_t = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32,name='Y_t')

        Y_t_2 = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 4], dtype=tf.float32, name='Y_t_2')


        is_training=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)
        lr=tf.placeholder(shape=[],dtype=tf.float32,name='learning_rate')
        dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='dropout')

        f=3
        Yhat1,Yhat2= main_proccess(E_t1,E_t2,E_t3,E_t4,E_t5,E_t6,S_t1,S_t2,S_t3,S_t4,S_t5,S_t6,S_t7,S_t8,S_t9,S_t10,P_t,Ybar,S_t_extra,f,is_training,num_units,num_layers,dropout)
        Yhat1=tf.identity(Yhat1,name='Yhat1')

        print('Yhatttttttttt',Yhat1)
        # Yhat2 is the prediction we got before the final time step (year t)
        total_parameters = 0
        for variable in tf.trainable_variables():
            # shape is an array of tf.Dimension
            print(variable)
            shape = variable.get_shape()
            #print(shape)
            # print(len(shape))
            variable_parameters = 1
            for dim in shape:
                #   print(dim)
                variable_parameters *= dim.value
            # print(variable_parameters)
            total_parameters += variable_parameters
        print("total_parameters",total_parameters)

        with tf.name_scope('loss_function'):

            RMSE,_,_,Loss1=Cost_function(Y_t, Yhat1)

            _, _, _, Loss2 = Cost_function(Y_t_2, Yhat2)


            #Yhat2 is the prediction we got before the final time step (year t)

            Tloss=tf.constant(l,dtype=tf.float32)*Loss1+tf.constant(le,dtype=tf.float32)*Loss2

        RMSE=tf.identity(RMSE,name='RMSE')
        with tf.name_scope('train'):

            update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
            with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
                train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(Tloss)


        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

        sess = tf.Session()

        sess.run(init)
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./tensorboard")
        writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

        t1=time.time()
       A = []

        for i in range(4, 39):
            A.append([ i - 4, i - 3, i - 2, i - 1, i])

        A = np.vstack(A)
        A += 1980
        print(A.shape)

        dic = {}

        for i in range(39):
            dic[str(i + 1980)] = X[X[:, 1] == i + 1980]



        avg = {}
        avg2 = []
        for i in range(39):
            avg[str(i + 1980)] = np.mean(X[X[:, 1] == i + 1980][:, 2])
            avg2.append(np.mean(X[X[:, 1] == i + 1980][:, 2]))

        print('avgggggg', avg)

        mm = np.mean(avg2)
        ss = np.std(avg2)

        avg = {}

        for i in range(39):
            avg[str(i + 1980)] = (np.mean(X[X[:, 1] == i + 1980][:, 2]) - mm) / ss

        avg['2018'] = avg['2017']
        #avg['2017']=avg['2016']


        #a2 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2008'], axis=0), [avg['2008']]))

        #a3 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2009'], axis=0), [avg['2009']]))

        #a4 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2010'], axis=0), [avg['2010']]))

        #a5 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2011'], axis=0), [avg['2011']]))

        #a6 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2012'], axis=0), [avg['2012']]))

        #a7 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2013'], axis=0), [avg['2013']]))

        a8 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2014'], axis=0), [avg['2014']]))

        a9 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2015'], axis=0), [avg['2015']]))
        a10 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2016'], axis=0), [avg['2016']]))

        a11 = np.concatenate((np.mean(dic['2017'], axis=0), [avg['2017']]))

        mean_last = np.concatenate((a8, a9, a10,a11))

        validation_loss=[]

        train_loss=[]

        for i in range(Max_it):

            out_tr = get_sample(dic, A, avg,batch_size_tr, time_steps=5, num_features=316+100+14+4)

            # I = np.random.randint(m_tr, size=batch_size_tr)

            # Batch_X_g = X_training_g[I]

            Ybar_tr=out_tr[:, :, -1].reshape(-1,5,1)

            Batch_X_e = out_tr[:, :, 3:-1].reshape(-1,6*52+100+14+4)

            #Batch_X_e=Batch_X_e.reshape(batch_size_tr,-1)
            Batch_X_e=np.expand_dims(Batch_X_e,axis=-1)
            Batch_Y = out_tr[:, -1, 2]
            Batch_Y = Batch_Y.reshape(len(Batch_Y), 1)

            Batch_Y_2 = out_tr[:, np.arange(0,4), 2]


            #I = np.random.randint(m_tr, size=batch_size_tr)

            #Batch_X_g = X_training_g[I]
            #Batch_X_e = np.expand_dims(out[:,3:],axis=-1)
            #Batch_Y = out[:,2]
            #Batch_Y = Batch_Y.reshape(len(Batch_Y), 1)

            if i==60000:
                learning_rate=learning_rate/2
                print('learningrate1',learning_rate)
            elif i==120000:
                learning_rate = learning_rate/2
                print('learningrate2', learning_rate)
            elif i==180000:
                learning_rate = learning_rate/2
                print('learningrate3', learning_rate)



            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={ E_t1: Batch_X_e[:,0:52,:],E_t2: Batch_X_e[:,52*1:2*52,:],E_t3: Batch_X_e[:,52*2:3*52,:],
                                           E_t4: Batch_X_e[:, 52 * 3:4 * 52, :],E_t5: Batch_X_e[:,52*4:5*52,:],E_t6: Batch_X_e[:,52*5:52*6,:],
                                           S_t1:Batch_X_e[:,312:322,:],S_t2:Batch_X_e[:,322:332,:],S_t3:Batch_X_e[:,332:342,:],
                                           S_t4:Batch_X_e[:,342:352,:],S_t5:Batch_X_e[:,352:362,:],S_t6:Batch_X_e[:,362:372,:],
                                           S_t7: Batch_X_e[:, 372:382, :], S_t8: Batch_X_e[:, 382:392, :],
                                           S_t9: Batch_X_e[:, 392:402, :], S_t10: Batch_X_e[:, 402:412, :],P_t: Batch_X_e[:, 412:426, :],S_t_extra:Batch_X_e[:, 426:, :],
                                           Ybar:Ybar_tr,Y_t: Batch_Y,Y_t_2: Batch_Y_2,is_training:True,lr:learning_rate,dropout:0.0})

            if i%1000==0:



                out_tr = get_sample(dic, A, avg, batch_size=800, time_steps=5, num_features=316 + 100 + 14 + 4)

                # I = np.random.randint(m_tr, size=batch_size_tr)

                # Batch_X_g = X_training_g[I]

                Ybar_tr = out_tr[:, :, -1].reshape(-1, 5, 1)

                Batch_X_e = out_tr[:, :, 3:-1].reshape(-1, 6 * 52 + 100 + 14 + 4)

                # Batch_X_e=Batch_X_e.reshape(batch_size_tr,-1)
                Batch_X_e = np.expand_dims(Batch_X_e, axis=-1)
                Batch_Y = out_tr[:, -1, 2]
                Batch_Y = Batch_Y.reshape(len(Batch_Y), 1)

                Batch_Y_2 = out_tr[:, np.arange(0, 4), 2]

                out_te = get_sample_te(dic, mean_last, avg,np.sum(Index), time_steps=5, num_features=316+100+14+4)
                print(out_te.shape)

                Ybar_te = out_te[:, :, -1].reshape(-1, 5, 1)
                Batch_X_e_te = out_te[:, :, 3:-1].reshape(-1,6*52+100+14+4)
                Batch_X_e_te = np.expand_dims(Batch_X_e_te, axis=-1)
                Batch_Y_te = out_te[:, -1, 2]
                Batch_Y_te = Batch_Y_te.reshape(len(Batch_Y_te), 1)
                Batch_Y_te2 = out_te[:, np.arange(0,4), 2]





                rmse_tr,yhat1_tr,loss_tr = sess.run([RMSE,Yhat1,Tloss], feed_dict={ E_t1: Batch_X_e[:,0:52,:],E_t2: Batch_X_e[:,52*1:2*52,:],E_t3: Batch_X_e[:,52*2:3*52,:],
                                           E_t4: Batch_X_e[:, 52 * 3:4 * 52, :],E_t5: Batch_X_e[:,52*4:5*52,:],E_t6: Batch_X_e[:,52*5:52*6,:],
                                           S_t1:Batch_X_e[:,312:322,:],S_t2:Batch_X_e[:,322:332,:],S_t3:Batch_X_e[:,332:342,:],
                                           S_t4:Batch_X_e[:,342:352,:],S_t5:Batch_X_e[:,352:362,:],S_t6:Batch_X_e[:,362:372,:],
                                           S_t7: Batch_X_e[:, 372:382, :], S_t8: Batch_X_e[:, 382:392, :],
                                           S_t9: Batch_X_e[:, 392:402, :], S_t10: Batch_X_e[:, 402:412, :],P_t: Batch_X_e[:, 412:426, :],S_t_extra:Batch_X_e[:, 426:, :],
                                           Ybar:Ybar_tr,Y_t: Batch_Y,Y_t_2: Batch_Y_2,is_training:True,lr:learning_rate,dropout:0.0})

                rc_tr = np.corrcoef(np.squeeze(Batch_Y), np.squeeze(yhat1_tr))[0, 1]

                rmse_te,yhat1_te,loss_val = sess.run([RMSE,Yhat1,Tloss], feed_dict={ E_t1: Batch_X_e_te[:,0:52,:],E_t2: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*1:2*52,:],E_t3: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*2:3*52,:],
                                           E_t4: Batch_X_e_te[:, 52 * 3:4 * 52, :],E_t5: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*4:5*52,:],E_t6: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*5:52*6,:],
                                           S_t1:Batch_X_e_te[:,312:322,:],S_t2:Batch_X_e_te[:,322:332,:],S_t3:Batch_X_e_te[:,332:342,:],
                                           S_t4:Batch_X_e_te[:,342:352,:],S_t5:Batch_X_e_te[:,352:362,:],S_t6:Batch_X_e_te[:,362:372,:],
                                           S_t7: Batch_X_e_te[:, 372:382, :], S_t8: Batch_X_e_te[:, 382:392, :],
                                           S_t9: Batch_X_e_te[:, 392:402, :], S_t10: Batch_X_e_te[:, 402:412, :],P_t: Batch_X_e_te[:, 412:426, :],S_t_extra:Batch_X_e_te[:, 426:, :],
                                           Ybar:Ybar_te,Y_t: Batch_Y_te,Y_t_2: Batch_Y_te2,is_training:True,lr:learning_rate,dropout:0.0})

                rc = np.corrcoef(np.squeeze(Batch_Y_te), np.squeeze(yhat1_te))[0, 1]


                print("Iteration %d , The training RMSE is %f and Cor train is %f  and test RMSE is %f and Cor is %f " % (i, rmse_tr, rc_tr, rmse_te, rc))

                validation_loss.append(loss_val)

                train_loss.append(loss_tr)

                print(loss_tr, loss_val)





    out_te = get_sample_te(dic, mean_last, avg,np.sum(Index), time_steps=5, num_features=316+100+14+4)

    Batch_X_e_te = out_te[:, :, 3:-1].reshape(-1,6*52+100+14+4)
    Ybar_te = out_te[:, :, -1].reshape(-1, 5, 1)
    Batch_X_e_te = np.expand_dims(Batch_X_e_te, axis=-1)
    Batch_Y_te = out_te[:, -1, 2]
    Batch_Y_te = Batch_Y_te.reshape(len(Batch_Y_te), 1)
    Batch_Y_te2 = out_te[:, np.arange(0, 4), 2]

    rmse_te,yhat1 = sess.run([RMSE,Yhat1], feed_dict={ E_t1: Batch_X_e_te[:,0:52,:],E_t2: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*1:2*52,:],E_t3: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*2:3*52,:],
                                           E_t4: Batch_X_e_te[:, 52 * 3:4 * 52, :],E_t5: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*4:5*52,:],E_t6: Batch_X_e_te[:,52*5:52*6,:],
                                           S_t1:Batch_X_e_te[:,312:322,:],S_t2:Batch_X_e_te[:,322:332,:],S_t3:Batch_X_e_te[:,332:342,:],
                                           S_t4:Batch_X_e_te[:,342:352,:],S_t5:Batch_X_e_te[:,352:362,:],S_t6:Batch_X_e_te[:,362:372,:],
                                           S_t7: Batch_X_e_te[:, 372:382, :], S_t8: Batch_X_e_te[:, 382:392, :],
                                           S_t9: Batch_X_e_te[:, 392:402, :], S_t10: Batch_X_e_te[:, 402:412, :],P_t: Batch_X_e_te[:, 412:426, :],S_t_extra:Batch_X_e_te[:, 426:, :],
                                           Ybar:Ybar_te,Y_t: Batch_Y_te,Y_t_2: Batch_Y_te2,is_training:True,lr:learning_rate,dropout:0.0})


    print("The training RMSE is %f  and test RMSE is %f " % (rmse_tr, rmse_te))
    t2=time.time()

    print('the training time was %f' %(round(t2-t1,2)))
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, './model_soybean', global_step=i)  # Saving the model


    return  rmse_tr,rmse_te,train_loss,validation_loss




BigX = np.load('./soybean_data_soilgrid250_modified_states_9.npz') ##order W(52*6) S(100) P(14) S_extra(4)
X=BigX['data']

X_tr=X[X[:,1]<=2017]

X_tr=X_tr[:,3:]




M=np.mean(X_tr,axis=0,keepdims=True)
S=np.std(X_tr,axis=0,keepdims=True)
X[:,3:]=(X[:,3:]-M)/S


X=np.nan_to_num(X)
index_low_yield=X[:,2]<5
print('low yield observations',np.sum(index_low_yield))
print(X[index_low_yield][:,1])
X=X[np.logical_not(index_low_yield)]
del BigX

Index=X[:,1]==2018  #validation year验证年份

print('Std %.2f and mean %.2f  of test ' %(np.std(X[Index][:,2]),np.mean(X[Index][:,2])))


print("train data",np.sum(np.logical_not(Index)))
print("test data",np.sum(Index))

Max_it=350000      #150000 could also be used with early stopping
learning_rate=0.0003   # Learning rate
batch_size_tr=25  # traning batch size
le=0.0  # 使用最终时间步长之前的时间进行预测的损失权重
l=1.0    # 使用最终时间步长预测的损失权重
num_units=64  # LSTM celss 的隐藏单元数量
num_layers=1  # LSTM单元层数

rmse_tr,rmse_te,train_loss,validation_loss=main_program(X, Index,num_units,num_layers,Max_it, learning_rate, batch_size_tr,le,l)




 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\pycharmprojects\CNN-RNN-Yield-Prediction-master\CNN_RNN_soybean.py", line 703, in <module>
        rmse_tr,rmse_te,train_loss,validation_loss=main_program(X, Index,num_units,num_layers,Max_it, learning_rate, batch_size_tr,le,l)
```

error：

File "D:\pycharmprojects\CNN-RNN-Yield-Prediction-master\CNN_RNN_soybean.py", line 520, in main_program
out_tr = get_sample(dic, A, avg,batch_size_tr, time_steps=5, num_features=316+100+14+4)
File "D:\pycharmprojects\CNN-RNN-Yield-Prediction-master\CNN_RNN_soybean.py", line 317, in get_sample
out[i, j, :] = np.concatenate((X[r2, :],np.array([[ym]])),axis=1)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (396) into shape (434)

This is a deep neural network with tensorflow framework, because I'm a newbie, so I don't understand what it means and how to solve it

Comment: Please post all the relevant code as text, and the full error message